# How can I resolve this error?

Tags: ios, audio

First sorry about my english

I has a problem with my code, I try to do a sound program but appears this error in my code:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('CFURLRef' (aka 'const struct __CFURL *') and 'CFURLRef')
```

and this is my full code:

```
- (IBAction)tocar:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundfileURLRef; 
soundfileURLRef *CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Botao", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 SoundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundfileURLRef, &SoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CFBundleCopyResourceURL` line is messed up, an equals turned into an asterisk;

```
soundfileURLRef *CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, 
                          (CFStringRef) @"Botao", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
```

...should be...

```
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
                          (CFStringRef) @"Botao", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code your wrote is the one you actually use, this line is odd:

```
soundfileURLRef *CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Botao",
    CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
```

The asteriks (`*`) should be equlas (`=`)

I think it should be

```
soundfileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Botao", 
    CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
```